# HowTo use shared angular 2 components along with Angular2 web application and webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to use shared angular-2 components via copying them into my another angular-2 web project's node_modules folder. Unfortunately, it is not working.

You can see whole project at [Ng2-Webpack-Webpack](https://github.com/jkumawat/Ng2-Webpack-With-CDN)

Problem scenario is as following,

I have two Project, Angular2Spa and Angular2-CDN.

Angular2-CDN has shared angular components and guards etc.

Currently, I have implemented my auth.guard.ts for authentication dummy check.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { tokenNotExpired, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    publicRoutes: any;

    constructor( @Inject(Router) private _router: Router,
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.publicRoutes = {
            'login': true
        };
    }

    canActivate() {
        console.log("Activated Route");

        return true;
    }
}
```

I am copying this file via gulp task into Angular2Spa's node_modules/shared.

gulp.file

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='typescript:compile' AfterBuild='module:copy' />

var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var paths = {};
paths.webroot = path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot');
paths.app = path.join(paths.webroot, 'app');
paths.ng2App = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Angular2Spa');
paths.ng2AppShared = path.join(paths.ng2App, 'node_modules', 'shared');

gulp.task('module:copy', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            path.join(paths.app, '**')
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.ng2AppShared));
});

gulp.task('typescript:compile', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject({
        target: 'es5',
        moduleResolution: 'node',
        experimentalDecorators: true,
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    });

    return gulp.src([
        path.join(paths.app, '**/*.ts')
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app));
});
```

Problem arise when i want to use auth.guard in my Angular2Spa project which use Webpack.

While navigating to Counter (view) then it failed and throw error for

> No provider for AuthGuard!

My query is,

**Is there any better way to use shared components into another webpack and Angular2 web app without copying them into Node_modules? Or how to resolve this sharing component issue?**

Your help and suggestion will be highly appreciable!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a another way **`npm link`**. Instead of copy and paste use npm link to tie one project to another. Google npm link and follow documentation, you will find there what you are looking for.

Comment: npm link will not help to resolve the problem but yeah definitely its a good alternative approach. Thank you.